onDestroy() function not working on Foreground Service
I am trying to restart foreground services after user clear the recent app list or memory. Now app forced kill without showing anything. What I think is this onDestroy method not working on upper mention task. Please gys give me a better solution.
KeyPoint: Need to restart service after user clear the recent app. I know latest update restricted some of this services. Is there any solutions please help me!
What I tried,
Foreground Service

import android.Manifest
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.app.job.JobInfo
import android.app.job.JobScheduler
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.PowerManager
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.location.Priority
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationAvailability
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult

class ForegroundService: Service() {

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {


        createForegroundNotification()


        Log.d("MyPersistentsService","Services started")


        return START_STICKY

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        scheduleRestart()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun scheduleRestart() {
        val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val restartIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            this,
            0,
            restartIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        val triggerAtMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 1000
        alarmManager.set(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            triggerAtMillis,
            pendingIntent
        )
        Log.d("Service","Restart in 60 seconds")
    }

    private fun createForegroundNotification(){
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"persistent_service_channel")
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText("Service Running")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .build()
        startForeground(1, notification)
    }

} ```


Does onDestroy not run or does it just not restart the service?

It's not display any message or anything also not restart service after doing recent app clean

#onDestroy is not called always whilst exiting (see). try doing your processing in #onUnBind.
